# Woocommerce move product with specyfic title to end of the list

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to move the specyfic product with text on title to the end of the list in archive page for example "Etui Iphone 11 PRO" so the products with "etui" in title will move at the end. The best solution will be to create list with titles and moving it desc. I already have solution to move to the end product which are out of stock

```
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status', 2000);
}

function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
  
    if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
    $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
    $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
    $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```